# Required-Bundle defiend in plugin manifest not resolving at runtime

Tags: osgi, eclipse-rcp, rcp, osgi-bundle

Let me explain the problem this way. I have a plugin A and a plugin B. Plugin B is a required bundle in plugin A.
Now plugin A is part of a product. When I create the product and try executing the workflow which is using this plugin A it errors out:

```
at null : null : null.(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ReferenceMap.put(ReferenceMap.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.getBundle(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
```

This is issue is not occuring if this bundle B is not added as dependency/Required-Bundle in A.

I have tried adding plugin B to Bundle-Classpath of manifest but it was of no use. I suspect the plugin A OSGi bundle is getting corrupted due to adding B as required bundle.

*How can I resolve this ? Any suggestions are welcome.*

**UPDATE**: Added minimal info on the 2 manifest files:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: ******
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_222
Bundle-Description: Some implementation
Bundle-SymbolicName: B;singleton:=true
Require-Bundle: *, 
 org.eclipse.core.runtime, org.eclipse.ui;resolution:=optional
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Bundle-Copyright: ***
Bundle-DocURL: http://www.*.com/
Bundle-Vendor: **
Import-Package: j,k,l, org.eclipse.jface.layout;
 resolution:=optional, org.eclipse.swt, org.eclipse.swt.events, org.ec
 lipse.swt.internal.ole.win32, org.eclipse.swt.layout, org.eclipse.swt
 .ole.win32, org.eclipse.swt.widgets
Bundle-ContactAddress: ****
Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI: true
Export-Package: B;version="3.4.3", C;version="3.4.3", D;version="3.4.3"
Bundle-Name: B
Bundle-Version: 3.4.3
Bundle-ClassPath: .
Bundle-Localization: properties/****/i18n-resources



Manifest-Version: 1.0
Export-Package: A;version="1.0.12
 .SNAPSHOT", E;version="1.0.1
 2.SNAPSHOT"
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-ClassPath: .
Built-By: someone
Bundle-Name: A
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.2.1
Bundle-Copyright: ****
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5
Require-Bundle: *, B, *, org.eclipse.core.runtime, org.eclipse.jfac
 e, org.eclipse.osgi, org.eclipse.ui.workbench
Bundle-Vendor: **
Bundle-ContactAddress: **
Bundle-Version: 1.0.12.SNAPSHOT
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_80
Bundle-Activator: someting
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Description: Plugin used to launch HTML Wizards through the SWT
 .Browser
Bundle-SymbolicName: A;singleton:
 =true
Bundle-DocURL: 
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

UPDATE:
Also tried adding B under Import-package header of manfest of A. Still did not work.

Comment: You cannot add another bundle to the `Bundle-Classpath`. The `Bundle-Classpath` is to add in the bundle contained JARs or class files to the classpath of the bundle. So you say, bundle A has bundle B as `Require-Bundle`. Bundle B has `Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy` and both are part of the product, right? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of both `MANIFEST.MF` and the product definition files.

Comment: @howlger added minimal info on the manifest files. I have replaced the confidential info and changed the actual plugin names with A and B as described in the question.

Comment: How are you building the RCP (note that the old Export RCP is deprecated). Have you listed both of the plug-ins in the .product file (everything required must be listed in that)?

Comment: What is the actual exception message before the "at ...." traceback? Crashing in ReferenceMap is not normal

Comment: With which Java version do you run it? Bundle A was built with Java 7 (`Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_80`) and requires Java 5 or higher (`Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5`); bundle B was built with Java 8 (`Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_222`) and requires Java 8 or higher (`Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8`); so at least Java 8 is required to run it.

Comment: @howlger its java 8 .

Comment: So A is part of a product, is B also in the same way?

Comment: A has always been part of the product but B is newly added. It was not a part previously. @nitind

Comment: Please explain how you added B to the product and how you created the RCP application. Since B was added as a `Require-Bundle` to A, the `Bundle-Version` of A was incremented and then built, right?